# Azure B2C: Getting List of Built-in Claims for Custom Policies

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy

While the [Azure Starter Pack for B2C](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-b2c-custom-policy-starterpack) is helpful for getting started with creating custom policies, is there an actual list of built-in claims that one can reference?  There are several claims that are referred in several of the files, though I have no clue of their purpose or why they're needed (for example upnUserName, nca, resource_id, etc.).

I did find some pages, such as [Graph API reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/azure/ad/graph/api/api-catalog) or [Customize Claims](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-claims-mapping), though I'm not sure if these are the goto page for getting all built-in claims.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find list of all such claims from two places

1. User profile attributes documentation - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/user-profile-attributes#azure-ad-user-resource-type
2. User attributes blade in Azure Portal. The Built in user attributes are almost same for user flows and custom policies.

Comment: Thank you for the link.  Is there a link on documentation for claims specific to protocols?  For example, ```nca``` appears to be specific for local account authentication

Comment: that will not be available in a central place. It will depend on technical profiles.

Comment: Fair enough.  Would I find it under the How-to Guides for Identity Providers or the ClaimsProviders reference for custom policies?

Comment: You will find them under Technical profiles actually,

Comment: And please accept the answer if it helped you :)

Comment: So via https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/technicalprofiles ?